# How do I extract mixed elements from a long list in pandas/ python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I've the following long list in a dataframe that needs cleaning:
df=pd.DataFrame({'Points':
['Team A v Team Bn\n13 Jan 20:00 +147 st\nScoreO (1.5)\n1.142\nScoreU (1.5)\n5.50\nScoreO (2.5)\n**1.48**\nScoreU (2.5)**\n2.65**\nScoreO (3.5)\n2.15\nScoreU (3.5)\n1.666\nScoreO (4.5)\n3.60\nScoreU (4.5)\n1.285\nScoreO (5.5)\n6.50\nScoreU (5.5)\n1.10']})

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Points':
['Team A v Team Bn\n13 Jan 20:00 +147 st\nScoreO (1.5)\n1.142\nScoreU (1.5)\n5.50\nScoreO (2.5)\n1.48\nScoreU (2.5)\n2.65\nScoreO (3.5)\n2.15\nScoreU (3.5)\n1.666\nScoreO (4.5)\n3.60\nScoreU (4.5)\n1.285\nScoreO (5.5)\n6.50\nScoreU (5.5)\n1.10']})
```

Desired results:  `1.48\n2.65`

So from the list I want to extract the actual float score inside (2.5) for both ScoreO & ScoreU to achieve the above objective.

I've tried slicing but I'm far from my goal hence will not attempt to show my dismal failure (be kind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, know your input. Your actual string looks like

```py
Team A v Team Bn
13 Jan 20:00 +147 st
ScoreO (1.5)
1.142
ScoreU (1.5)
5.50
ScoreO (2.5)
1.48
ScoreU (2.5)
2.65
ScoreO (3.5)
2.15
ScoreU (3.5)
1.666
ScoreO (4.5)
3.60
ScoreU (4.5)
1.285
ScoreO (5.5)
6.50
ScoreU (5.5)
1.10
```

Now, you want to get a *float* numeric value that is located on lines below the lines equal to `ScoreO (2.5)` and `ScoreU (2.5)`.

Thus, you can set the *context* with either `Score[OU] \(2\.5\)\n` or just `\(2\.5\)\n` since this is enough to find the context you need to start matching from, and then you may either use `(.+)` (you already know the value you need is a whole line) or `\d+\.\d+` (since you know it is a float value).

So, you may use either of the two solutions below:

```py
>>> df['Points'].str.findall(r'Score[OU] \(2\.5\)\n(\d+\.\d+)').str.join('\n')
0    1.48\n2.65
>>> df['Points'].str.findall(r'\(2\.5\)\n(.+)').str.join('\n')
0    1.48\n2.65
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nOCo0W/1)

Comment: Thank you for the solution; 100% working the way I like! Opted for solution no.2 as I found it very easy to follow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `str.extractall` with `Score(?:O|U) \(2\.5\)\n([0-9.]+)`, where `Score(?:O|U) \(2\.5\)\n` will match `ScoreO (2.5)` or `ScoreU (2.5)` plus a new line, and `([0-9.])+` captures the score at the next line:

```
df.Points.str.extractall('Score(?:O|U) \(2\.5\)\n([0-9.]+)').unstack(level=1)

#           0      
# match     0     1
# 0      1.48  2.65
```

If you need to join the results:

```
df.Points.str.extractall('Score(?:O|U) \(2\.5\)\n([0-9.]+)')
  .groupby(level=0)
  .agg('\n'.join)

#            0
#0  1.48\n2.65
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on that when the other solution was posted but still, here is something that can be useful. You can convert this into dataframe, for later-on selection of other scores (e.g. 3.5)

```
>>> pat=r'ScoreO.+\((?P<ScoreO>\d+[.]\d+)\)\n(\d+[.]\d+)\nScoreU.+\((?P<ScoreU>\d+[.]\d+)\)\n(\d+[.]\d+)'
>>> df = df.Points.str.extractall(pat).droplevel(1)
>>> df.columns=['Score0','result1','ScoreU','result2']
>>> df 
  Score0 result1 ScoreU result2
0    1.5   1.142    1.5    5.50
0    2.5    1.48    2.5    2.65
0    3.5    2.15    3.5   1.666
0    4.5    3.60    4.5   1.285
0    5.5    6.50    5.5    1.10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can covert the dataframe into a list, split it by lines, and iterate through the smaller strings to find your data:

```
def findScores (df, search_term = "2.5"):
    lst = df.to_numpy().tolist() #converts df into list
    lst = lst[0][0].split("\n") #makes a list of strings
    result = ['ScoreO', 'ScoreU']
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] == f'ScoreO ({search_term})':
            result[0] = lst[i+1]
        elif lst[i] == f'ScoreU ({search_term})':
            result[1] = lst[i + 1]
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you. Will give feedback,